# Error: The type or namespace name 'Interface' does not exist in the namespace (are you missing an assembly reference)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am developing an application using Xamarin and got stuck into this error. The error has been generated from my **.Droid** project while building the solution (Clean Solution is successful). The 'Interface' is a folder which is present inside my **Portable PCL** project. Basically I want to implement an interface (declared inside my Portable project) into my .Droid project. I have already tried to refer that Interface folder with **using** keyword but it says  *does not exist*. And since the folder is not getting referenced, all the interfaces inside that folder are also not getting referenced.

The below code is of **.Droid** project file in which interface has to be implemented.

```
using ProjectName;
using ProjectName.Interface;
using Xamarin.Forms;

[assembly: Dependency(typeof(FileName))]
namespace ProjectName.Droid
{
    class FileName : InterfaceName
    {
        ....
    }
}
```

The below code is of one of the **Portable** project interface file inside Interface folder.

```
using System;
using ProjectName;

namespace ProjectName.Interface
{
     public interface InterfaceName
     {
          ....
     }
}
```

When I try to **Add Reference** of Portable project into .Droid project it says:

> Unable to add reference to Portable project. The current project's target is not one of or compatible with the targets of Portable Project.

Please Note:

1. I am using **Visual Studio 2019**.
2. My Portable project **Target Frameworks** are: .NET Framework 4.5, ASP.NET Core 1.0, Windows 8, Windows 8.1, Windows Phone Silverlight 8.
3. My Droid project Target is **Android 11.0**(API Level 30 -R)
4. I have already added **Mono.Android.dll** file inside Portable as well as Droid project.
5. I have tried deleting **bin** and **obj** folder of both projects but didn't worked at all.
6. I am unable to add Reference of my Portable project into my Droid project.
7. Also, all the interfaces inside 'Interface' folder are **public**.

Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: `ProjectName` is the actual project name? Can you also share the code of interface? Portable project and the Droid project have the same name?

Comment: No. The name of project is something else. It was just for reference. And Yes, both projects have the same name and both are included in same solution.

Comment: The interface code has been added into the question. @Chetan plz refer it.

Comment: You have added project reference of Portable project to the Droid project?

Comment: No it says "Unable to add reference to Portable project. The current project's target is not one of or compatible with the targets of Portable Project.

Comment: This sounds like a very old project that is still using PCL instead of .NET Standard

Comment: So your root problem is not being able to reference the PCL project in Droid project. I think you should look for the solution of that issue rather than looking for why interface is not found.

Comment: Hey @Chetan I have searched for that one but unable to find any specific solution. Any suggestions from your side?

Comment: Currently, we generally use Xamarin Forms Project rather than Portable Project. In Xamarin Forms Project, we don't have this problem.  So, please switch to Xamarin Forms Project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem by myself. I have edited **ProjectName.Droid.csproj** file and manually inserted reference code for my Portable Project. No need to convert into .net standard at all. All errors are gone. Thank You everyone who contributed. Cheers.